# How can I launch an applescript.scpt file from the terminal and pass terms / variables?

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal, applescript

I have an applescript that does something along these lines:

```
using terms from application "Quicksilver"
    on open theseitems
        repeat with aitem in theseitems
            display dialog aitem as text
        end repeat
    end open
end using terms from
```

But what I'd like to do is be able to start running a particular `applescript.scpt` file via the Terminal and pass in a variable, like a path to a file.

```
osascript ~/applescript.scpt /path/to/my/file.txt
```

and then have the Applescript run with access to that parameter. In this case it would (hopefully) display a dialog with that path, `/path/to/my/file.txt`

I know I could achieve that by doing something like

```
osascript -e "display dialog "~/path/to/file.txt"
```

But the point is not to display a dialog with Applescript, rather it's more about knowing if I would be able to pass a variable in to a script file.

Answer (score 8):

In the script you pass in the arguments with the `on run` like this :

```
on run arg
  --do whatever you want with arg
end run
```

If more than one argument is specified the `arg` variable is a list.
[image]

[image]