# Run commands in existing terminal window

Tags: terminal, applescript, automator

I would like to use an applescript to run a command in an existing open terminal window. It is not a normal bash terminal window it's a java terminal for a game server console (minecraft)

I have never written applescript before so I am trying to learn as I go. It seems that all the snippets and tutorials I have found all open a new bash window but that wont work in this case. e.g.

```
tell application "Terminal"
    try
        do script "save-all"
    end try
end tell
```

How can I use applescript to run commands in this existing window?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    do script "save-all" in front window    
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to either A) compile your Applescript via ScriptEditor and then call that compiled script from your Java terminal somehow ([does the "`osascript`" command work in that terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8424930/how-can-i-launch-an-applescript-scpt-file-from-the-terminal-and-pass-terms-var)) or B) you need to [write a native Objective-C tool](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2084/_index.html) that you can call from some kind of glue layer in your Java app.

[Here is also a related question I just discovered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159719/applescript-from-java-on-mac-os-x-10-6) that may have some useful answers/hints for you.